# Bootstrap sliders text overlay is disabling nav links

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I have used a bootstrap slider with text overlay and it is disabling the nav bar when I scroll down the page. When the text is level with the nav bar which is fixed, the links are disabled

Not sure if it is a bootstrap bug as I have used other sliders in the past which seem fine. The only think it that is is a one page website with many sections so the navbar needs to be fixed

```
<!------------NavigationBar------------>
<section id="nav-bar">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo1.png" alt=""></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#top">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#about">ABOUT US</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#services">SERVICES</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#team">OUR TEAM</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#price">PRICE PLANS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#testimonials">TESTIMONIALS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</section>

<!------------Slider------------>   
<div id="slider">
    <div id="headerSlider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#headerSlider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#headerSlider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#headerSlider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="img/img1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h5>Business Consultants Is Who We Are</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="img/img2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h5>Create A Business Niche</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="img/img3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h5>Business Plan Support</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#headerSlider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#headerSlider" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
</div>




/*-----------Navigation----------*/
#nav-bar{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}

.navbar-brand img{
    height: 80px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.navbar-nav li{
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.navbar-nav li a{
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
}

#nav-bar ul li a:hover{
    color: #586949!important;
}

.navbar{
    background: #fff;
}

.navbar-toggle{
    border: none!important;
}

.nav-link{
    color:green!important;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;
}

/*-----------Slider----------*/
#slider{
    width: 100%;
   background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.1);
}

/*.carousel-item img{
    height: 800px;
}*/

.carousel-caption{
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    bottom: initial!important;
}

.carousel-caption h5{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```